# utorrent Hash: element not found

Tags: utorrent

***Problem:***

I keep getting ***Hash: Element not found errors.***

> ***Technical Details:***
>
> - uTorrent 3.2.3 (latest as of this writing)
>
>   - Running about 30 Torrents (all downloading)
> - Win 7 64 bit
> - Dell N5050 :sigh:

***Symptoms:***

- Force recheck is disabled (sometimes)
- When I resume the torrent, as it halts when this happens, it proceeds smoothly until the next ***Hash: Element not found*** error

  - It doesn't happen at a particular %age

***Solutions Attempted:***

Searched online a lot to find a few below

1. **Re-download elsewhere.** Set download folder and change it and re-download the torrent. ***NO! DOESN'T WORK!*** and its FRUSTRATING that I'd to DELETE my 90% downloaded torrent!!
2. **Good 'ol thump**. Swear at the screen making heavy fist thumps and hand gestures. Surprisingly, this doesn't work!
3. **Force recheck.** Doesn't help and sometimes not available.
4. ***Disk I/O errors.*** Came across an article which said this might due to Disk I/O errors.

   - Realized I was using a **DELL** laptop
   - Realized HDD had failed on a previous DELL
   - Tried ***Solution #2*** again. Same results.
   - Seemed like the most likely explanation to the problem, hence read articles about HDD checking and downloaded a few suggested softwares to check HDD Health
   - Interestingly, the HDD was a OK

None of these worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ***working*** solution turned out to be pretty simple.

> ***Check your Anti-Virus!***

My antivirus was quietly quarantining a few suspected files.

> ***Added those files to the exclusion list.***

All is well again.

Answer (score 9):

I got this error when my hard drive ran out of disk space, so I think it is related to some file / disk access issue, depending on where you are writing to

Comment: I had the same issue, Drive storage was full. Thank you

Answer (score 7):

I was trying to download some large files to a network drive (Windows XP to Samba) and I was getting the same `Element Not Found` error.

In my case, enabling the disk cache has solved the issue. I had to **uncheck** the `Disable Windows caching of disk writes` and `Disable Windows caching of disk reads` options under *uTorrent Options -> Preferences -> Advanced -> Disk Cache* (this way enabling the cache).

[image: utorrent preferences screenshot]

Source: http://forum.utorrent.com/topic/34159-error-element-not-found/page-2#entry251137

I really think this question belongs to [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) though.

Comment: It's funny that torrenting to a SAMBA network drive seem to be so seldomly done that most of my searches just have people tell me it's a HDD problem, but of course it isn't because when I plug it directly to my computer it didn't have any issues.  This little fix seem to did it for v2.2.1.  Awesome and thank you!